# Is the mapping from an empty set to an empty set smooth?

Tags: functions, smooth-functions

For a function/mapping of the form $f(x) = x^2$, we can perform differention to check if it is smooth.

But for a mapping from empty set to empty set, what is the corresponding function $f(x)$ and how do we differentiate it to check for smoothness?

Comment: A function is smooth if it's smooth at every point.  Since there are no points in the empty set, the condition is vacuously satisfied. Therefore, the function is smooth.

Comment: Can you spell out differentianility in terms of $\forall, \exists,...$ then it is easier to check. When you try to check something for the emty set, you need to see whether it is an statement of the form $\forall x\in \emptyset$ (then it is true) or of the form $\exists x\in \emptyset$ (then it is false).